# Как правильно "весьтИ" или "вестИ"?

Tags: орфография

Постоянно мучаюсь над "весьтИ" или "вестИ"?

Контекст, например, такой: "разработку месторождения надо вес*ти только летом"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, без мягкого знака: "разработку месторождения надо **вести** только летом".

Comment: Спасибо! Выручили!

Comment: Обращайтесь :-))

Answer (score 3):

Мягкий знак пишется (сохраняется)у глаголов в повелительном наклонении во множественном числе. Правда,перед ТЕ: ответь - ответьте, оставь - оставьте. Может быть, это правило некоторых сбивает с толку.